# How do I wait() for the snackbar onDismissed process to finish?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, wait, snackbar

I'm want to start a process after the snackbar onDismissed is completed.

```
if (snackbar != null){
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
```

Since the  snackbar onDismissed is asynchronous the activity will finish before the onDismissed task is complete.

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                if (event != DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION) {
                    // Some work to be done.
            }
```

I realise I can call finish() in onDismissed but there are other actions which cause the snackbar to dismiss and I don't want them to finish the activity.
Is there a way to wait for the snackbar process to finish before continuing through code?

Comment: What are other actions which cause the snackbar to dismiss.   Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Android Documentation for [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback.html). You can use DISMISS_EVENT_MANUAL to signify that the dismiss of a snack bar coming from a dismiss() call.

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
            if (event == DISMISS_EVENT_MANUAL) {
                // Some work to be done.
                activity.finish()
            }
        }
```

Another option is that you extend the Snackbar.Callback(). Something like

```
class MyCallback extends Snackbar.Callback {
      Runnable run;
      @Override
      public void onDismissed(...) {
           // Do something
           if (run) run.run();
      }
}
BaseCallback<Snackbar> callback = new MyCallback();
snackbar.addCallback(callback);
```

And then do this when you want to finish on dismiss.

```
if (snackbar != null){
    callback.run = new Runnable() {
         void run() {
             finish();
         }
    };
    snackbar.dismiss();
} else {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: The second option worked well. There were several action which dismissed the snackbar and needed to have their thread started once the onDismissed had finished it's process.